# JSON Parsing Issue With Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working code but it is somewhat failing: my JSON response is a valid JSON as I checked it on JSOnLint.com.

So here is the piece of code which is making trouble

```javascript
$.post("items.cfm",{"term":request.term})
    .done(function(data){
        alert(data);
        try{
          var obj = $.parseJSON(data),
          values = [];
          alert(obj[x].id.split('~')[3]);

          for(var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++){
              values.push({
                "label":obj[x].text, "value":obj[x].id,
                "price":obj[x].id.split('~')[3]
              });
          }
          response(values);
        } catch(e) {
          alert(e);
        }
})
```

If I start my JSON with the following:

```javascript
{
    "text": "Blue CPR Pocket Mask",
    "id": "128177000003239005~Blue~YES~10.75"
}, {
    "text": "CPR Face Shields",
    "id": "128177000000138987~CPs~YES~41.83"
}
```

… it throws an error:

> **SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position**

… but if I start with:

```
[{
        "text": "Blue CPR Pocket Mask",
        "id": "128177000003239005~Blue~YES~10.75"
    }, {
        "text": "CPR Face Shields",
        "id": "128177000000138987~CPs~YES~41.83"
    }
]
```

a valid JSON, but it fails with my code as i try to parse it and use its value but it says to me that id is undefined. so what should i do to make it work.

**Update #1**

I followed everyone's method and gave a try and now it started me the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '4592' in
```

Comment: You have two JSON objects, not one. So, treat them as two different ones or combine them as an array or inner-objects of another object. Moreover, why you want to parse? It's already JSON, isn't it?

Comment: what does `console.log(obj)` inside your try return?

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
alert(obj[x].id.split('~')[3]);
```

this line leads to an error:

```
x is not defined
```

move this line into for-loop to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be parsing it as it in array. 
Also, variable 'x' that you are using in alert function is above the for loop. That is why you are getting the error 'id' is undefined.

Also, this worked for me.

```
var data = [{
            "text": "Blue CPR Pocket Mask",
            "id": "12817700000323900"
         },
        {
             "text": "CPR Face Shields",
        "id": "128177000000138987"
        }
        ]
        function test1(){
           var obj = data
            values = [];
            console.log(obj)

            for(var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++){
                values.push({"label":obj[x].text, "value":obj[x].id, "price":obj[x].id.split('~')[3]});
            }
        }
        test1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a each loop, your json is valid if you have [] because you have multiple object that need to be in a array

```js
var data = [{
  "text": "Blue CPR Pocket Mask",
  "id": "128177000003239005~Blue~YES~10.75"
}, {
  "text": "CPR Face Shields",
  "id": "128177000000138987~CPs~YES~41.83"
}];
var values = [];
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {

  values.push({
    "label": obj.text,
    "value": obj.id,
    "price": obj.id.split('~')[3]
  });
});
console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you are receiving a valid json object/string

Comment: hi, i changed the code and now i am getting this `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '4592' in `

Answer (score 0):

"x" in `alert(obj[x].id.split('~')[3])` is undefined. 
Put it in the loop may solve problem:

```
  for(var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++){
      alert(obj[x].id);
      values.push({
        "label":obj[x].text, "value":obj[x].id,
        "price":obj[x].id.split('~')[3]
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is just because the index of the `obj` variable.

So here is the solution:

```
$.post("items.cfm",{"term":request.term})
    .done(function(data){
        alert(data);
        try{
          var obj = $.parseJSON(data),
          values = [];
          //alert(obj[x].id.split('~')[3]); 
          //this guy is creating the issue.
          //since he's out of the loop where x is declared(out of scope)
          //Put it inside the loop and thins will work fine.

          for(var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++){
              alert(obj[x].id.split('~')[3]);  //Moved here(x is defined in the for loop)!
              values.push({
                "label":obj[x].text, "value":obj[x].id,
                "price":obj[x].id.split('~')[3]
              });
          }
          response(values);
        } catch(e) {
          alert(e);
        }
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

It is wrong JSON:

```
{},{};
```

It is right JSON:

```
[{},{}];
```

OR

```
{};
```